# Deploying python website on Heroku, not working

Tags: python, heroku

I have deployed my python website on heroku, but when I visit the page, I see a generic heroku "application error" message.  Then when I go into terminal and check heroku logs, I see this:

```
2013-09-04T04:33:04.130527+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python bin/app.py`
2013-09-04T04:33:06.871127+00:00 app[web.1]: http://0.0.0.0:8080/
2013-09-04T04:34:06.937646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2013-09-04T04:34:06.937868+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-09-04T04:34:08.199958+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-09-04T04:34:08.158024+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2013-09-04T04:34:09.013423+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=arcane-lake-2908.herokuapp.com fwd="71.20.1.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-04T04:34:11.107423+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=arcane-lake-2908.herokuapp.com fwd="71.20.1.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-04T04:35:54.768913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=arcane-lake-2908.herokuapp.com fwd="71.20.1.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-09-04T04:37:35.374279+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=arcane-lake-2908.herokuapp.com fwd="71.20.1.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I'm not sure what any of this means.  Also when I run foreman start I get the following message, I'm not sure if this is related:

```
21:43:00 web.1  | started with pid 1694
21:45:28 web.1  | 127.0.0.1:51458 - - [03/Sep/2013 21:45:28] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 404 Not Found
```

procfile:

```
web: python bin/app.py
```

`app.py`:

```
import web

urls = ( '/hello', 'Index' )

app = web.application(urls, globals())
render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
 def GET(self):
     return render.hello_form()
 def POST(self):
     form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
     greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
     return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
 app.run()
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for your app.py here?

Comment: 'import web

urls = (
  '/hello', 'Index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        return render.hello_form()

    def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="Nobody", greet="Hello")
        greeting = "%s, %s" % (form.greet, form.name)
        return render.index(greeting = greeting)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()'

Comment: im having issues posting the code correctly @Rohit

Comment: Sorry. I meant to ask for Procfile.

Comment: About the code, for Procfile, you can edit it into the main post.

Comment: I added your code to the question, just double check that it matches your file.

Comment: I deleted /hello from the urls at the top.  I have NO idea what this does, or why i decided to delete that, but the page loads now.  Is what's in parenthesis next to url supposed to contain things that actually exist? for example, does /hello refer to a hello.html file that should exist somewhere in my project?  I have no idea, this stuff is so frustrating.

Comment: So it's working now? Also, is your app.py in the bin directory?

Comment: app.py is in the bin directory yes.  Am I correct in thinking that the reason this did not work before is because i never created a hello.html page?

Comment: No. So that is just a map. You can try putting /hello back and then going to yourdomain.com/hello. Now that you removed it, it must be showing you the page at yourdomain.com/

Comment: OH, I added the /hello back and now when I go to my domain it says not found.  HOWEVER, if i go to my domain.com/hello, the program is there and works.  But why do I have to go to .com/hello?  How do I just make it work on mydomain.com

Comment: Use '/' in the place of '/hello'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36764/discussion-between-rohit-and-donnaloia)

Comment: You mean in the web browser?  I just tried that, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web.py assigns the port to be 8080. While Heroku assigns a different port. That is probably the reason it was not binding to the $PORT. 
You can try modifying your Procfile to be

```
web: python bin/app.py ${PORT}
```

Heroku will take care of filling the PORT value.